# comparing lists at a previous index

Tags: python

I have got 2 lists for which I would like to compare to one index before :

```
for (min,max) in zip(csv_parse(2010)['min'],csv_parse(2010)['max']):
```

basically I would like something like this :

**if min > min(back one increment) and max < max (back on increment)**

then, do something .

Thanks !

Comment: ... And what are you going to do with the result of the comparison? You shouldn't be using `min` and `max` as variable names, btw; that hides built-ins (which I vaguely suspect might be the exact ones you need to solve your problem concisely...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import izip
prev_min, prev_max = float('inf'), float('-inf')

for new_min, new_max in izip(csv_parse(2010)['min'], csv_parse(2010)['max']):
    if (new_min > prev_min) and (new_max < prev_max):
        #do something
    prev_min, prev_max = new_min, new_max
```

Switch the values of `prev_min` and `prev_max` above the loop if you **do** want to "do something" on the first item.

Also, you probably want to use [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for something like this. You also probably don't want to be parsing your csv twice (once for min, once for max) but I don't know for sure without seeing what `csv_parse` is.

Comment: @agf: It would be much more robust to use *infinite* constants for the initial values: `prev_min = float('inf')`; this way, no knowledge of the actual values in `csv_parse(…)[…]` is necessary.  Furthermore, it is strongly advised to *not* redefine the `min` and `max` names; in fact, this solution breaks Python's `min()` and `max()`.

Comment: @EOL -- should have noticed the min, max thing, good call. Nice on the `inf`s too. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
min_values = csv_parse(2010)['min']
max_values = csv_parse(2010)['max']

for (prev_min, current_min, prev_max, current_max) in zip(min_values, min_values[1:], max_values, max_values[1:]):
    if current_min > prev_min and current_max < prev_max:
        …
```

The idea behind this solution is to create a list of "previous values" along with a list of "current values" (`…[1:]`).

Comment: Seems wasteful to make copies of the list, instead of just retaining the trailing values?

Comment: @agf: This is indeed not memory efficient; however, this works well with lists of reasonable size.  Furthermore, I find that this version is slightly more legible than the "trailing values" version, as the logic of the code is shown in a single, simple line.